# Algorithm to Calculate number of events using start and end dates/time

Tags: php, algorithm, count

I have a set of events that has a start and end time. I would like to generate a array of time and number of events at that time the value changes for creating a graph. As of now, I am calculating the value by multiple iterations of the start and end times. Is there any other way?

E.g.

```
Event 1: Jan 1 to Jan 10
Event 2: Jan 6 to Feb 6
Event 3: jan 8 to Feb 1
```

i should get an array like

```
Jan 1: 1
Jan 6: 2
Jan 8: 3
Jan 11: 2
Feb 2: 1
Feb 7: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of all start and end times, together with information whether an event starts (1) or ends (-1) on this date:

```
[(Jan 1 , 1), (Jan 10, -1), (Jan 6, 1), (Feb 6, -1), (Jan 8, 1), (Feb 1, -1)]
```

Sort the array by date:

```
[(Jan 1 , 1), (Jan 6, 1), (Jan 8, 1), (Jan 10, -1), (Feb 1, -1), (Feb 6, -1)]
```

Walk through the array, keep a counter and add dates to your array as appropriate. You might want to coalesce various occurrences of the same date into a single entry.

(This is not O(n), but I think the aim is to be better than the original O(n²).)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the events as a sorted list (earliest date first) then
Really crappy pseudocode follows

```
running_count = 0
list_of_end_dates = [];
vector_of_date_events_pairs = [];
For Each item in the events collection { 
    running_count += 1
    while(queue.tail < item.end_date) {
        queue.pop_back()
        running_count -= 1
    }
    vector_of_date_events_pairs.push(item.start_date, running_count)
    list_of_end_dates.push_front(item.end_date)
}
```